# Optimizing C++ code

Tags: c++

I'm designing classes for my application (network tool). I this base class:

```
class Descriptor
{
    // ...

    public:
        virtual void data_read (void);
        virtual void data_write (void);
        virtual void data_error (void);

     protected:   
        int socket_descriptor;
    // ...
}

class TcpClient :
    public Descriptor
{
    // ...
}
```

Many classes are based on Descriptor. I monitor sockets' events using epoll. When I want to look for events on TcpClient object I add the object's socket and pointer to this object to epoll, code:

```
epoll_event descriptor_events;

descriptor_events.events = EPOLLIN;
descriptor_events.data.fd = this->socket_descriptor;
descriptor_events.data.ptr = this;

epoll_ctl (epoll_descriptor, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, this->socket_descriptor, &descriptor_events);
```

I dispatch epoll events in separate thread in this way:

```
Descriptor *descriptor (NULL);

// ...

return_value = epoll_wait (epoll_descriptor, events, 64, -1);

while (i < return_value)
{
    descriptor = (Descriptor *) (events [i]).data.ptr;

    if ((events [i]).events & EPOLLOUT)
        descriptor->data_write ();
    if ((events [i]).events & EPOLLIN)
        descriptor->data_read ();
    if ((events [i]).events & EPOLLERR)
        descriptor->data_error ();

    i++;
}
```

Program is going to handle a lot of data in the epoll thread, so it mean, that virtual functions will be called many times there. I'm wondering about runtime cost of this solution.

I'm also thinking about two other implementations (however I'm not sure if the're much faster):

```
typedef void (*function) (Descriptor *) EventFunction;

class Descriptor
{
    // ...

    public:
        EventFunction data_read;
        EventFunction data_write;
        EventFunction data_error;

     protected:   
        Descriptor (EventFunction data_read,
                    EventFunction data_write,
                    EventFunction data_error);

        int socket_descriptor;
    // ...
}
```

or use CRTP.

Maybe you have other idea of implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless proven otherwise, your original design looks fine to me.

The first rule of optimization is to measure first, then fix only hotspots that really exist. You'll be surprised where your code spends its time. Dwelling on the distinction between virtual functions and function pointers is almost certainly premature optimization. In both cases the compiler will generate code to jump to a function pointer, though with virtual functions the compiler will have to look up the vtable first. Write idiomatic C++ code to do what you want, then profile it if you have performance problems.

(I do have one comment about your class `Descriptor`: Unless you're planning on having generic data_read(), data_write(), and data_error() methods I'd recommend making them pure virtual methods.)

Comment: What about CRTP? It's a bit ugly but shouldn't provide any runtime overhead.

Comment: If CRTP is an option, feel free to go for it. But for low-level socket I/O, the CPU isn't often the bottleneck. Most likely it makes absolutely no difference, because you just don't send/receive that many packets per second.

Comment: +1 to jalf. Efficient low-level socket I/O generally comes down to extremely tight and efficient use of threads. For some operating systems, writing the most scalable servers even requires kernel-level programming! On Windows, we have I/O Completion Ports.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, your best bet for optimizing this code is probably to completely replace it with [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). As described, you're essentially re-implementing the heavily scrutinized and well tested ASIO library. Unless you're absolutely certain you must roll your own I/O library, you'll probably save yourself a tremendous amount of development & optimization time by just using an existing solution.

Comment: Well I want to reinvent the wheel (I'm a computer science student) and I want simply try to write such things on my own to improve skills and extend knowledge. Moreover I'm going to play with SCTP protocol, so Boost.Asio may not suit my requirements.

Comment: @Goofy: If Boost.Asio doesn't suit your SCTP requirements perhaps it might be useful to extend it and contribute your improvements to the Boost community.  That way you could both improve your own skills and allow others to leverage your findings.

Comment: @Goofy: Well in that case, re-invent away! Excellent choice of areas too. I agree with Void in that adapting Boost to support SCTP is an idea worth considering. If you're not an expert in C++ when you start, you almost certainly will be by the time you finish ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Under the [don't reinvent the wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091778/reinventing-the-wheel-vs-good-practice-for-a-beginner) umbrella, I'd suggest looking at [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) since it offers most of the functionality you have described in your sample code.